# How to redraw a stored CGPath as a Bezier path if the original CGPoints are lost

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I redraw a stored CGPath as a Bezier path if the original CGPoints were not stored?

This is the code, but it does not work (the path is redrawn in standard mode rather than in Bezier mode):

```
CGMutablePathRef UpathFREEHAND = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPoint firstPointFH = [[pointArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
CGPathMoveToPoint(UpathFREEHAND, NULL, firstPointFH.x, firstPointFH.y);

for (int i = 0; i < [pointArray count]; i++)
    {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(UpathFREEHAND, NULL, [[pointArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x, 
        [[pointArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y);
    }

CGMutablePathRef _TempPathForUndo = UpathFREEHAND;

//Add PATH object to array
[UPath addObject:CFBridgingRelease(_TempPathForUndo)];

//Load PATH object from array
_TTempPathForUndo = (__bridge CGMutablePathRef)([UPath objectAtIndex:i]);

// Now create the UIBezierPath object.
UIBezierPath *bp;
bp = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
bp.CGPath = _TTempPathForUndo;

CGContextAddPath(context, bp.CGPath);
//Color, Brush Size parameters, Line cap parameters..
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Do you at least have one variable that you know so that you can approximate something mathematically?  Even sans programming, it's pretty hard to make a parabola with no known variables!  Or skip all of this nonsense and write something to NSUserDefaults like a sane human being.

Comment: So I guess that the CGPath itself does not contain information anymore of the CGPoints that were originally used to create it, right?

Comment: Can't you just create a Bezier path from the CGPath using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgpath]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method from [`UIBezierPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBezierPath):

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)CGPath
```

The reuse of a `CGPath` is valid. Check this example adding `TestView` in a `UIViewController` and linking a `UIButton` to force the redraw when clicking on it with `[_testView setNeedsDisplay]`:

```
// TestView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIView {

    CGMutablePathRef _path;
    BOOL _nextDraws;
}

@end

// TestView.m

#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    BOOL firstDraw = !_nextDraws;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (firstDraw) {
        NSLog(@"first draw");

        _path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(_path, NULL, 0, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(_path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGPathCloseSubpath(_path);
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, _path);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

        _nextDraws = YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"next draws");

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
        UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:_path];
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, bezierPath.CGPath);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    CGPathRelease(_path);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I do the following but I do get an error and it crashes.                         //Convert path to Bezier path (does not work)
UIBezierPath* bp = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:_TTempPathForUndo];

Comment: Error: CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply_transform(CGAffineTransform const&):
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x0)

Comment: Thanks. Before posting more code, could u please clarify one thing? If the original path was created as a non Bezier one, would "bezierPathWithCGPath" automatically convert it into a Bezier one without the need to manually compute the 2 midpoints?

Comment: Yes. Check the example attached in the question.

Comment: I got why it was crashing: because I was equaling the CGMutablePathRef to the UIBezierPath and because in order to add the Bezier path I did not know that I should have appended ".CGPath". Thank you. Although it does not crash anymore, still the path is drawn not as a Bezier one because the method "bezierPathWithCGPath" doesn't get called. Should I add anything in the header file?

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that my answer solved your question. I so, please accept the answer :) About your other issue I cannot help you without any code...

Comment: I gladly accept your answer although technically the Path does not get redrawn as Bezier yet. I am not familiar with + methods, only ever have used the ones starting with -. Maybe if you could kindly explain how to use + (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)CGPath properly.

Comment: Thx :) methods that start with + are class methods, and in this case is a factory method, that (in brief) are used to generate objects. - methods or instance methods run into an instantiated variable. In order to use `bezierPathWithPath` you have to use with a CGPathRef. Check this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Comment: The documentation is excellent and I have implemented the code as in the examples of your link, but the path still does not get drawn as Bezier!! I have added my code in the original question in case anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with *the path still does not get drawn as Bezier*? And, what are you expecting to be drawn?

Comment: I mean it's not smooth. When the path is drawn initially I am using a Bezier algorithm and it gets drawn super smooth. Then I save this path into an array and when I retrieve it with the Undo I expect it to be redrawn in the same smooth way. Instead it doesn't. So I guess that the suggested conversion to Bezier does not magically create a smooth curve, right? If so, then how can I retrieve the points of the path in order to process them with the Bezier algorithm? Is there a way to do so or do I need to save all the original CGPoints of the path in an array when the path is first created?

Comment: This becomes a new question so I suggest you to create a new one with this issue. Anyway, check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html (Adding Curves to Your Path) to recreate the bezier curves.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version of atxe's answer:

```
let myCGPath: CGPath = // stored CGPath or path taken from another object
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: myCGPath)
```